# Firebird Classic server on Ubuntu 13.10 listen to remote connections

Tags: firebird2.5, xinetd

I've installed Firebird Classic on Ubuntu (13.10) and I need to open it to remote connections. netstat -an on port 3050 shows this:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

I tried editing `/etc/xinet.d/firebird25` to listen to all on eth0, I tried to edit `firebird.conf` to Bind to all interfaces. But still I can't connect via remote on that port. Firewall is disabled.

Comment: I think this question is better suited to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ (or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/ )

Answer (score 6):

I answered this in
https://askubuntu.com/questions/373090/ubuntu-server-13-10-and-firebird-2-5

From a fresh install:

```
sudo su
apt-get install xinetd
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
apt-get update
apt-get install firebird2.5-classic                 
netstat -an | grep 3050  #shows the problem: not binding to  0.0.0.0
nano /etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf
#comment out all RemoteBindAddress = XXXX
nano  /etc/xinetd.d/firebird25
#set  bind                    = 0.0.0.0
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-classic
netstat -an | grep 3050  #shows the fixed as binding to 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: There is more information about this on (mpopa) Mariuz's Blog: http://mapopa.blogspot.ro/2011/04/securing-firebird-25-superclassic-in.html